# iOS. addsubview to master-detail app

Tags: iphone, ios, master-detail

I have a master-detail application with news. It works. In detail controller i used `UIWebView`.
I created **comments-class** with **xib** and am trying to add it to my detail view.
Comments are `UITableViewController`. 
After that i can see only comments, not detail-text.

I tried to scroll my **webview** and there is no text. But in **detailviewController** i did `NSLog` for my text and saw it. If i set `newsTextHeight` to **480** i see an empty view.

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat newsTextHeight = 250;
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    CommentsViewController *commentController  = [[CommentsViewController alloc] init];

    NewsItem *newsItem = [news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    detailViewController.description = newsItem.description;
    detailViewController.title = newsItem.date;
    commentController.news_id = newsItem.news_id;
    detailViewController.news_id = [newsItem.news_id intValue];
    int views = [newsItem.viewsCnt intValue];
    views++;
    NSString *strFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",views];
    newsItem.viewsCnt = strFromInt;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    //[self.navigationController presentedViewController];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    detailViewController.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
    [detailViewController addChildViewController:commentController];
    [commentController didMoveToParentViewController:detailViewController];

    [detailViewController.view addSubview:commentController.view];

    detailViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, detailViewController.view.bounds.size.width, newsTextHeight);

    commentController.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(detailViewController.view.frame.size.height, 0, 0, 0);

    [commentController release];
    [detailViewController release];

}
```

results: http://s18.postimg.org/5cv8ftbbd/detail.png

Comment: I have done differently. I needed to display the detailed news with comments. I use UITableView with 2 sections. In 1 i use UIWebView, in 2 tableview

Answer (score 0):

What Kiattisak is getting at is that the problem can be that your view `detailViewController.view.frame` is using autolayout. And therefor won't be able to be resized programmatically. (This is if you are not using storyboards)

In InterfaceBuilder, highlight your view:

[image]

And untick the `Use Autolayout` box in the first tab of the attributes inspector.
[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help. :(